# How to prevent a function from firing off when the user refreshes a page?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a game, in which a user logs in, clicks a "Start Game" button, and a random token (and team JSON) is generated after a user clicks that button and navigates to the game page. The functionality works in that our Firebase database is updated each time the game page is loaded with a brand new token/team object, but what I want to prevent is the function from firing off if the user keeps refreshes the page while still logged in.

What is the best way to track logged-in sessions? Would trying to track cookies be a better approach?

Comment: Server-side session management (such as Firebase Auth API) and client-side tools such as cookies and/or localStorage are all useful for resolving this use case as @sub6resources has answered below.

Which tools you use and how you approach the solution, are highly dependent upon your system architecture.

Comment: Where do you have this function call written? Can you share code of this function?

Answer (score 1):

If you are already using Firebase, then you can take a look at the Firebase Auth APIs, which handle sign-in sessions very well.

If you are just storing game sessions, and nothing secure or valuable, then cookies will be an okay option, just remember that they can be edited by the user.

If you want to keep a page from calling a function on refresh, a good way to do this would be with cookies as well. You can create a cookie when the user first visits the page, then it checks for the cookie when the page loads, and if it doesn't contain the cookie, then you can call the function. You can also give a way for the user to delete the cookie if they want to start a new game.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried

event.preventDefault()

https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: The problem is not the *default* event handling, it's the JS event handling (and how to distinguish between arriving on a page for the first time and refreshing the page)